# compare two lists with zeros en larger numbers

Tags: python

I have to compare two lists of elements with the same length. (as an example `[0,562,256,0,0,856]` and `[265,0,265,0,874,958]`. Both list have an amount of zeroes and an amount of numbers above 249. I want to compare these lists. If at an index both lists have a number different from `0` the number should be saved in a list. The result should be two lists with the same length with only numbers above `249` (in the example `[256,856]` and `[265,958]`). Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: It is helpful to show the code you have tried and to describe the manner in which it does not work as intended.  Also, the way you present this it sounds like you're asking for the answer to a homework assignment.  Help with homework is fine, but just the answer is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe we will find a better way,but

```
list1 = [0,562,256,0,0,856]
list2 = [265,0,265,0,874,958]
rest1 = []
rest2 = []
result1 = []
result2 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
if list1[i] and list2[i]:
    rest1.append(list1[i])
        rest2.append(list2[i])
for i in range(len(rest1)):
if rest1[i] >249 and rest2[i]>249:
        result1.append(rest1[i])
    result2.append(rest2[i])
print(result1,result1)
```

Comment: if you remove the first for loop it still works but it is an excellent solution I think!

Comment: thank you for your appreciate. i did the first loop because you said that "If at an index both lists have a number different from 0 the number should be saved in a list."

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip()` to pair up the elements of each list:

```
listA = [0,562,256,0,0,856]
listB = [265,0,265,0,874,958]

combined = zip(listA, listB)
resultA = [a for a, b in combined if a and b]
resultB = [b for a, b in combined if a and b]
```

gives:

```
>>> resultA
[256, 856]
>>> resultB
[265, 958]
```

You could also first use `filter()` to remove all pairs where one or the other element is 0:

```
combined = filter(lambda (a, b): (a and b), zip(listA, listB))
resultA = [a for a, b in combined]
resultB = [b for a, b in combined]
```